# I am not able to create project in android studio. Plugin error is showing. Also many plugin including java gradle could not be loaded

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am not able to create a new Android project. Whenever I am going to create a new project, it shows plugin error. Most of the plugin couldn't be loaded including java gradle. Some of the plugins are marked as red.

Look into the error:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Disable plugins that are red. Restart Android Studio
Once Android Studio is opened again, go to the same place and activate the same plugins again in the case of disabled plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the android studio and try to install the plugins again.Even after that if you get the same issue, unmark the red labeled plugins try to install others and then install these.